# Creating data.frame when multiple nodes <p></p> or siblings are under a parent <div>

Tags: r

As in the page below, multiple paragraphs are under the `<div>` element which results in printing only the first `<p>` when scraping the page.

http://www.epilepsy.com/connect/forums/living-epilepsy-adults/anyone-else-w-connection-vietnam-war

I've tried to add up all the `<p>` elements by using the code below

```
content = html_text(html_node(h, 'div.field-item.even > p'))
```

but then while all the `<p>`s are extracted the data frame cannot be saved
(with error saying "replacement has 6 rows, data has 1")

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I appreciate your help.

```
dataf <- data.frame(title=c(), content=c())
dataf
post.num <- 1

for(link in article_href){
    link = sprintf('http://www.epilepsy.com%s', link)
    print(link)
    h = read_html(link)

    title = html_text(html_node(h, 'div.panel-pane.pane-node-title.no-title.block'))
    title <- str_trim(title)
    str_replace_all(title, '[[:space:]]', '')
    print(title)


    content = html_text(html_node(h, 'div.field-item.even > p'))
    print(content)
    dataf[post.num, 'content'] = content


    post.num <- post.num + 1

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the formatting within the text content, you can just select the parent node of the `<p>`s instead:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

h = read_html('http://www.epilepsy.com/connect/forums/living-epilepsy-adults/anyone-else-w-connection-vietnam-war')

title <- h %>% html_node('div.pane-node-title h2') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
print(title)

content <- h %>% html_node('.field-name-field-body') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
print(content)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ! It worked fine in the loop. helps a lot!